# Como converter uma string em número direto do prompt?

Tags: javascript, string, number-format

Estou começando a aprender `JavaScript` e me preocupo em escrever um código **redundante/repetitivo**, tem alguma forma mais adequada de converter as strings do `prompt` em números antes de inserir no `array`?

```
function getPoints() {
    var point
    var points = []
    
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        point = prompt(`Pontuação obtida no exercício ${i+1}`)
        points[i] = Number(point)
    }
    return points
}
```

Comment: Não deu certo minha resposta Fabiana?

Comment: Deu sim. Do jeito que você colocou, usando o push parece melhor, mesmo. Mas a minha dúvida era se a conversão deveria ficar mais resumida, sem utilizar uma variável como essa do point para armazenar o valor convertido antes de inserí-lo no array.

Comment: Não há problemas em criar variável, que vai ser utilizado que é o caso, o problema do seu código era a falta de teste e só inserir dados númericos

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Com `parseInt` ([analisa um argumento string e retorna um inteiro na base especificada](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)) para converter os valor e `isNaN` ([determina se o valor é NaN ou não](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)) para verificar se o `parse` aconteceu com sucesso ou retornou `NaN`, também uma mudança na hora de criar as posições do `array`, com `push` que cria automáticamente a posição para inserir o novo valor, exemplo:

```js
function getPoints() {
    let points = [];    
    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        //porde ser parseFloat se o numero tiver decimais Ex: 1.5
        let point = parseInt (
          prompt(`Pontuação obtida no exercício ${i+1}`)
        )        
        if (!isNaN(point)) {
          points.push(point);
        }
    }
    return points
}
console.log(getPoints());
```

sendo que só serão inseridos valores númericos.